# Can't apply a colorFilter to text selection handles

Tags: android, material-design, nine-patch, android-bitmap

I'm trying to bring material text selection handles to my app. I got drawables from the SDK for middle/right/left handle (bitmaps) and text cursor (9-patch), and set:

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left_mtrl_alpha</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right_mtrl_alpha</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_alpha</item>
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/text_cursor_mtrl_alpha</item>
```

It works as expected. However, in Lollipop these drawables are tinted with a particular color in XML using the `android:tint` attribute, which I can't use on API<21. So I'm trying to set a color filter at runtime.

[image]

- Text cursor does not get tinted. I think this might be due to it being a 9 patch. How can a 9-patch drawable be filtered at runtime? I tried probably all of `PorterDuff.Mode`s.
- Right/left handles are black, while middle handle is white.

I.e., non of them is green as I would like. Why?

As you can see above, I set up four `ImageView` below my edit text, and they instead get tinted.

```
   private void setUpTextCursors() {
        Drawable left = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_left_mtrl_alpha);
        Drawable right = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_right_mtrl_alpha);
        Drawable middle = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_alpha);
        Drawable cursor = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_cursor_mtrl_alpha);
        ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(mGreenColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        /**
        * tint my ImageViews, but no effect on edit text handles
        */
        left.setColorFilter(cf); 
        right.setColorFilter(cf);
        middle.setColorFilter(cf);

        /**
        * no effect whatsoever
        */
        cursor.setColorFilter(cf);
   }
```

Looks like here we have both a 9-patch tinting issue - since filter fails even on test ImageViews - and an issue related to the fact that none of the applied filters get considered by the text selection manager.

Relevant source code about that is from the `TextView` [class](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) and from this `Editor` hidden [helper class](http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/sources/android-16/android/widget/Editor.java) which I found somehow. Spent some time on it but still can't tell why my filters are ignored.

---

To @pskink: let `cursor` be the filtered drawable, I can have:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/1"
    android:src="@drawable/cursor_drawable" />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@id/2" />
```

The first won't be tinted, but if I call `imageView2.setBackground(cursor)`, then it's tinted.
Also if I have

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/cursor_drawable</item>
```

this affects the edit selection (because I override the default cursor) but it's not tinted, again.

Comment: what does cursor.getPaint() return?

Comment: @pskink ..a non-null Paint object. What do you want to know about it?

Comment: did you try to step into setColorFilter with the debugger?

Comment: @pskink you are right, I have a null `mPaint` value. Why? Apart from that, filters get applied well on handles, as you can see in my test views. Issue there is that the selection manager accepts the drawables but ignores my filters. I added some source code links at the end.

Comment: i didn't go deep enough but it seems to be a bug, try first calling getPaint and then setColorFilter, does it change eanything?

Comment: @psking nice try - I get into `setColorFilter` with a non-null `mPaint`, and get out with a non-null `mColorFilter`. But still, both cursor and test imageviews are white.

Comment: set a breakpoint in draw(Canvas) then and see why your color filter is not applied

Comment: @pskink honestly I'm not able to see why.

Comment: what sdk level are you working with?

Comment: @pskink latest, but testing on API17.

Comment: Did you try to set this drawable, i mean "cursor" to some ordinary view? setBackground(cursor) ?

Comment: @pskink just tried, and it is tinted. It's like `android:src` for 9 patches still points to the original, non-filtered resource. Weird. And we said nothing about the edittext issue..

Comment: Ok i got lost,  how do you set left,  middle,  right and cursor Drawables? In your code i see tow you get them and set their color filter but how do you set them to some edit text attributes?

Comment: @pskink by style (see the beginning of my question). But I also set up some test views to test color filtering for `cursor`. Edited the end of my question with some explanation. Also added an answer, but not covering the  `cursor` issue.

Comment: in your activity add this: http://pastebin.com/q1pjquX8 (change R.drawable.cursor to R.drawable.text_cursor_material)

Comment: Did it work in your app?

Comment: Hey @pskink . Brilliant, I ended up using your solution for the other three resources as well, as my workaround was working only occasionally. Please post this as an answer, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to override the default Resources used by your Activity:

```
// your activity source file
Resources res;

@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    if (res == null) {
        res = new TintResources(super.getResources());
    }
    return res;
}
```

the custom Resources class will override `getDrawable()` method so you can intercept creating your Drawables and set up the color filter, for example:

```
class TintResources extends Resources {

    public TintResources(Resources resources) {
        super(resources.getAssets(), resources.getDisplayMetrics(), resources.getConfiguration());
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(int id) throws NotFoundException {
        Drawable d = super.getDrawable(id);
        if (id == R.drawable.text_cursor_material) {
            // setup @drawable/text_cursor_material
            d.setColorFilter(0xff00aa00, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

the same way you can setup other Drawables (@drawable/text_select_handle_*_material), note you need that not direct way since EditText doesn't have getter methods for accessing those Drawables

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point of checking for `res == null` (i.e., instantiating TintResources only once)? I miss some java fundamentals here. I would have simply called `getResources() { return new TintResources() }` .

Comment: Add Log.d there and see how often it is called,  many,  many times... But of course if you don't  care you can skip that extra steps and always return new TintResources

Answer (score 1):

This is just a partial answer, and we can also consider it quite bad, since it's a workaround. I was able to load just the handles (i.e., the BitmapDrawables) inside the edittext (or any other selection stuff) by pointing at XML files rather than at raw png files. I.e. I set:

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left_material</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right_material</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle_material</item>
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/text_cursor_material</item>
```

where these are xml drawables like:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/text_select_handle_left_mtrl_alpha" />
```

or

```
<nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/text_cursor_mtrl_alpha" />
```

If I filter these drawables, I found them tinted *both* in views *and* in selections. So I altered my method like such:

```
private void setUpTextCursors() {
    ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(mColorControlActivated, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    BitmapDrawable left = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_left_material);
    BitmapDrawable middle = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_middle_material);
    BitmapDrawable right = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_right_material);
    // NinePatchDrawable cursor = (NinePatchDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.text_cursor_material);
    left.setColorFilter(cf);
    right.setColorFilter(cf);
    middle.setColorFilter(cf);
    // cursor.setColorFilter(cf); this does not work: cursor still white!
}
```

However, while this works for `left`, `right`, and `middle`, something is still wrong with the 9-patch `cursor`, because I can't get it tinted.