# How to tint WebView text selection handles?

Tags: android, webview, tint

im trying to tint the long press selection handles in the webview. I am doing it via the colorXYZ attributes in theme. Works for textView, however not for WebView, which stays default green / blue

This is what I have, none of the attributes work for webview

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/gold</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/gold</item>
</style>
```

[image]

```
::selection {
  background: #FFAABB;
}
```

This only colors the selection rect

[image]

Comment: If you have a webview why aren't you using JS to do that?

Comment: How can I do that? I only tried ::selection in css, but that colors the selected rect

Comment: I don't know if you know Jquery Mobile? They have a function taphold that is that you press:  https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/

Comment: you mean handling the whole long click in js? im not looking to do that, I just want to change the color of the default text selection ui, which is normally easy for textviews, but webview seems to ignore this styling -- ive added a pic

Comment: See answer you can do it like that

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this with CSS.

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; 
}
```

You can find more info about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)

Comment: This only colors the color rect around the text, ommits the side handles, sa Ive said in the comments

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with selected rect? Can you explain better what it does? Because the screenshot what you placed it thought you just want to turn the blue in a other color. So that is what that does

Comment: Ive added another screenshot ... I want to tint the handles (and the rect also, but that works), unfortunatelly cant figure out how

Comment: I see the new screenshot. What do you want more? Do you want to blue buttons maybe also coloured in red?

Comment: No, I want to change the color of the 2 turqoise handles at the sides of the selection rect

Comment: Now I understand what you want.

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263596/cant-apply-a-colorfilter-to-text-selection-handles ?

Comment: I read that but adding my own drawables is a hassle, I dont care for this that much if that the workaround is that dirty, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem! I understand